# Extract text from X11 GUIs?

Tags: user-interface, testing, x11

I have a point-of-sale application written in Perl/Tk.  I use X11::GUITest to do automated testing of it, driving the app via hot-keys bound to the buttons and other widgets (it's normally touch-screen driven).  However, X11::GUITest doesn't have a way to "read" text back from the screen, so I resort to augmenting the app to write temp files as well as putting data on the screen. The test scripts then look at the temp files, not the GUI.  But I'd love to extend X11::GUITest or make a new CPAN module that can scrape text strings from X11 GUIs.  I'm not after graphics-to-text conversion; it's my (faint) understanding that somewhere in the depths of the X window system, label text and such are stored as text strings and rendered to bitmap form late in the pipeline (?).

Anyone have guidance on how to do this, or pointers on where to start?

Yeah, I know I should've adhered to better MVC separation and not actually test at the GUI level, but just below it; however reality got in the way and it is what it is!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to make your program work with an accessibility framework like [ATK](http://developer.gnome.org/atk/) (used in GTK applications) and then use that to query for the strings as a screen reader would have to for text-to-speech translation.   This is the approach taken by the [Linux Desktop Testing Project](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/) and [dogtail](https://fedorahosted.org/dogtail/) testing frameworks.  You get the bonus of using existing, well tested code and making your application more usable by disabled users (as may be required by laws such as the Americans with Disabilities Act in the US and similar laws in many other countries).

If your application is using modern font frameworks, like libXft2, this may be your only choice, as those strings are only in the client application, not the X server, and the character to pixmap conversion is done in the client.   (If your text is antialiased, it must be using these instead of the legacy X11 API's.)

Even with the legacy X11 API's though, the X server doesn't store the strings once the text to bitmap conversion is done, so there's no good way to query them short of intercepting them in that case.

Comment: Thanx.  Dogtail is a nice little tool, it seems very useful.  I've taken it for a walk, made a few scripts, and can drive gcalctool and gedit, etc with it.  But my own app doesn't appear in the AT-SPI browser nor can I drive it with dogtail.  Seems I've a bit more work to make my app accessible, which isn't such a bad thing anyway.  Now I know my next step...

Comment: Would you say that ATK is still the most promising project for this? Are you really saying that intercepting the applications' X11 API requests for their string rendering is the only option to get those strings (and their bounding boxes) from a separate, independent X11 client application?!

Comment: @matanster: Yes, atk is still the best option I know of, as fewer and fewer X11 applications send strings to the X server at all these days, with most sending pre-rendered images of text, giving you nothing to intercept.

Answer (score 1):

The program `listres` lists resources in widgets, including label texts and I think the contents of text entry boxes. You may be able to use its output directly, extracting what you need, or you may need to look at the source and see how it's done.

Comment: Thanx.  listres is a useful little tool; I've not seen it before.  But it doesn't show any of the text strings from my app.  It's probably because I don't have each string as a separate resource.

Comment: @Spook, oh, I assumed you were using some kind of toolkit. I guess Perl/Tk does not use resources.